# Application crashes when creating an object

Tags: c++, inheritance, input, crash, directx

I have a class which inherits from IDirectInputA interface.

here: http://pastebin.com/QuHP02ai

so, when i try to create object of this, application crashes (calls CorExitProcess from somewhere). What i did wrong?

p.s. Direct input v. 7

p.p.s.

this code creates object. I deleted some code from it, except the main part

```
IDirectInputA** ppDI;
HRESULT hr = _DirectInputCreateA(hinst, dwVersion, ppDI, punkOuter);
xDirectInputA xDI = new xDirectInputA((IDirectInputA*)(*ppDI));
```

Comment: Did you allocate memory for `m_di` pointer?

Comment: Can you please provide a code that creates xDirectInputA instance? What do you pass in constructor?

Comment: @Sasza: Please do not post links to code, but rather actual code. Try to post the *minimal* part of your source code that could give us an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: Instead of using the initialization list, do the copying inside the constructor body with a null check.

Comment: Not quite sure if this is the problem, but inside `Release` you perform `delete this`, do you create the object with `new`? Do you make sure not to use the object again after its `Release` has been called (that includes re-deleting it)? As Bojan said, we need to see the code using this object.

Comment: @Bojan Komazec: I dont need to allocate memory for it, because DirectInputCreateA must do it from itself, i think.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your instance, you pass a pointer to IDirectInputA, right? What pointer do you pass? If you pass an uninitialized or a null pointer, you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: updated my post. see above :) No, it can;t be null but I shall check it now from debugger.

Comment: Checked, it's not null. It's an object, initialized by DirectInputCreateA

Answer (score 0):

TBH what you are trying to do is more complicated than you think.  The problem arises in what exactly you are trying to do.  Are you trying to wrap IDirectInputA OR are you trying to completely re-implement it.

If you are trying to wrap it do the following:

```
IDirectInputA* pDI = NULL;
HRESULT hr = _DirectInputCreateA( hinst, dwVersion, &pDI, NULL );
```

Then create your derived class as follows:

```
class xDirectInputA : public IDirectInputA
{
protected:
    IDirectInputA* mpInternal;
public:
    xDirectInputA( IDirectInputA* pInternal ) :
         mpInternal( pInternal )

    HRESULT CreateDevice( REFGUID rguid, IDirectInputDevice** ppDirectInputDevice, IUknown* pOuter )
    {
        // Do what ever processing you need.
        return mpInternal->CreateDevice( rguid, ppDirectInputDevice, pOuter );
    }

    // Implement other functions.
};
```

Now you pass your xDirectInputA pointer around instead of the normal pointer returned from DirectInputCreate.  You can now intercept every message that goes through the class.

If you are trying to do your own full re-implementation it is a LOT more complicated.  You are going to need to fully implement the COM object.  You'll be best off putting a DInput.DLL alongside the executable that contains your implementation.  All in though this is only something you should try if you REALLY know what you are doing.

If you wish to learn COM fully I suggest purchasing [Essential COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634465) by Don Box.  Its a VERY helpful book.